# How to remove focus from a React Native TextInput on button click?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have a React Native `textInput` and a button and I would like to remove the focus from the `textInput` if I were to click on the button. Would that be possible?

My TextInput looks like this:

```
        <TextInput
            onChangeText={onChange}
            value={searchQuery}
            placeholder="Start typing to search or add your own"
            maxLength={80}
            onFocus={() => {
                setIsInputFocused(true);
            }}
            onBlur={() => {
                setIsInputFocused(false);
                setSearchQuery('');
            }}
            blurOnSubmit={true}
        />
```

And then I have a pressable element:

```
<View onPress={() => { //remove focus from Text Input }></View>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [useImperativeHandle](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#useimperativehandle) hook is the one you need here, And `forwardRef`, `useRef` hooks. I have created a new TextInput called `ControlledTextInput` to pass a react ref to it and expose the blur method outside (App component level). Note that there are two refs one is coming as a prop(to which we bind the functions) and the one inside `ControlledTextInput`(which is the ref to the actual text input)

```
import React, { useImperativeHandle, forwardRef, useRef } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TextInput, Button } from "react-native";

const ControlledTextInput = forwardRef((props, ref) => {
  const internalInputRef = useRef();
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    blur: () => {
      internalInputRef.current.blur();
    }
  }));

  return (
    <TextInput
      placeholder={"Type something"}
      style={styles.textInputStyle}
      ref={internalInputRef}
    />
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = useRef(null);

  return (
    <View style={styles.app}>
      <View style={styles.header}>
        <Text style={styles.title}>Focus lose when button click</Text>
      </View>
      <ControlledTextInput ref={inputRef} />
      <Button title="Click ME" onPress={() => inputRef.current.blur()} />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  app: {
    marginHorizontal: "auto",
    maxWidth: 500
  },
  header: {
    padding: 20
  },
  title: {
    fontWeight: "bold",
    fontSize: "1.5rem",
    marginVertical: "1em",
    textAlign: "center"
  },
  textInputStyle: {
    border: "2px solid black",
    maxWidth: 500,
    height: 50,
    textAlign: "center",
    fontSize: 20
  }
});

export default App;
```

React Native Codesandox:

[image: Edit remove focus from a React Native TextInput on button click]

Comment: @Bobimaru, check this out!!